# Recommended framework for a lightweight heartbeat app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a number of microservices I want to monitor for uptime.  I would like to make a call to each microservice to evaluate its state.  If the call succeeds, I know the application is "UP".

For an overly simplified use case, say I have the following three calls below.  I want to make a call to each of them every 10 minutes.  If all three respond with a 200, I want to modify an HTML file with the word "UP", otherwise the file should have the word "DOWN".

```
GET /api/movies/$movieId
POST /api/movies
DELETE api/movies/$movieId
```

Is Express/Node.js a good framework for this lightweight app?  If so, can someone point me to a GitHub stub that can get me started?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd say [Restify](http://restify.com/) would be a more appropriate framework over Express - lighter, more efficient and more suited to API-only servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Express and Restify would be fine for this sort of example if they're simply API's. The clincher would be your note about returning HTML.

> I want to modify an HTML file with the word "UP", otherwise the file should have the word "DOWN".

This would be more appropriate for Express as it allows you to use libraries like handlebars, mustache, pug, etc to do this HTML transformation.

You can use a scheduled job to check the status of your three applications, store that latest status check somewhere (a database, flat file, etc). Then a request to an endpoint such as `/status` on this new service would look up the latest status check, and return some templated HTML (using something like handlebars).

Alternatively, if you're comfortable with a bit of Bash you could probably just use linux / unix tooling to do this if you don't care about up-time history or further complexities.

You could setup apache or nginx to serve a file on the `/status` endpoint. Then use a cron job to ping all your health check URL's. If they all return without errors, you can update the file being served by nginx to say "UP", and if any errors are returned change the text to "DOWN".

This unix approach can also be done on windows if that's your jam. It would be about as light weight as you can get, and very easy to deploy and correct, but if you want to expand this application significantly in the future (storing up time history for example) you may wish to fall back to Express.

Answer (score 1):

Framework? You kids are spoilt. Back when I was a lad all this round here used to be fields...

Create two html template files for up and down, make them as fancy as you want.

Then you just need a few lines of bash run every 10 minutes as a cron job. As a basic example, create `statuspage.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for http in GET POST DELETE
do
    res=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -X $http  https://$1)
    if [ $res -ne 200 ]
    then
        cp /path/to/template/down.html /var/www/html/statuspage.html
        exit $res
    fi
done
cp /path/to/template/up.html /var/www/html/statuspage.html
```

Make it executable `chmod +x statuspage.sh` and run like this `./statuspage.sh "www.example.com/api"`

3 curl requests, stopping as soon as one fails then copying the up or down template to the location of your status page as applicable.

Comment: Very elegant solution and I like your attitude!  Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: To be honest I'd place myself firmly in the bash n00b category. An old hand would probably see this, laugh at how bloated it is and reduce it down to 4 lines of code. None of the cool kids are doing it, but I can say learning a bit about bash scripting has helped me out many times over the years. I'd definitely recommend it.